# D3D11 Freezes Windows Present

Tags: directx-11

When using D3D11 encountered a problem with an empty call context-> Present (0,0); OK. And if it goes before the draw, drawindexed ..., reezes windows completely.

Errors and warnings are missing in the assembly and execution.

```
GContext->VSSetShader(mVS->GetVertexShader(), NULL, 0);
GContext->PSSetShader(mPS->GetPixelShader(), NULL, 0); 
GContext->IASetIndexBuffer(NULL, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);
GContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST); GContext->Draw(3, 0); 
mSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
```

Comment: You should provide more details, for instance show your code.

Comment: Don't post your code as a comment, you can edit your post with the "edit" button right under the post.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the [debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) and look for messages in your debug window, and ensure you are checking every HRESULT for `SUCCEEDED` or `FAILED`.

Are you doing this in a 'tight loop'? Where are you processing your windows messages?

You should take a look at this [Windows desktop VS template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) for a good minimal rendering loop.

```
// Main message loop
MSG msg = { 0 };
while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        g_game->Tick();
    }
}
```

Here `Tick` is the Update loop and Render loop. See [StepTimer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/12/03/understanding-game-time-revisited.aspx) for a robust way to do the update timing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is some ignorance of init D3D code, `GContext->Draw(3, 0);`, you only want to draw a triangle.

So your can try `mSwapChain->Present(1, 0);` which will follow the Vsync like 60Hz and `present(0,0)` work as fast as it can, often 1000-5000Hz depend on computer. What is freeze you mean, you can not interact with window? That you can follow @Chuck Walbourn advice in main loop, like add the code after `mSwapChain->Present(0 or 1, 0);`.

As you know, you problem amostly an apearance of a bug, so don't worry.